# How can I replace a full line with a blank one by searching for a certain keyword

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, sed, scripting

I have a file that stores data like a catalog. I want to search a keyword in this file and replace the line which contains it, with a blank line.
The keyword will be saved in `$2`.

This is what I got so far:

```
sed '/$2/ c' " "' file.txt
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please use code tags for your sample Inputs and expected outputs in your post. So is this `$2` is a argument which you are passing to your script or is it something else, please let us know on same once.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, since I 'm new here I 'm gonna need those!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested with `GNU sed`:

```
$ a="blank"   # One can use "$2" instead of "$a" below. It would work the same.
$ sed -i "s/.*$a.*//g" test.txt  # -i option overwrites test.txt with the replacement
```

Example `test.txt`

```
$ cat test.txt
This is a test line
Replace this line with a blank line
This is another line
```

output:

```
This is a test line

This is another line
```

Answer (score 0):

Following simple `awk` may help you in same. I am considering that you are passing a variable to script while running it(by seeing your use of `$2` in your sample)

```
awk -v val="$2" '$0 ~ val{print "";next} 1' Input_file
```

In case it is a shell variable which has the value of keyword which you want to search then following could do the trick.

```
shell_variable_value="test_test_test"
awk -v val="$shell_variable_value" '$0 ~ val{print "";next} 1' Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
sed '/'"$2"'/c\
' file.txt
```

or with gnu sed

```
sed "/$2/z" file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v var="$2" 'index($0,var){$0=""}1' file
```

This will work even for keywords like: `.*`.